# JQ Mobile styles not applied when back button is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hdjLLdhw/)

The generate button links to a page and lists the text inputs. The output is normal. 
When back button is used and the Generate button is used again, inputs are listed. The li tags don't have the JQM classes attached to them.

I tried `$('#roleList').trigger('create');` but that didn't fix it :<
What's going on here?

Comment: There is an issue the second time you add items to the listview, because you are completely destroying the markup. Should this issue also be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add more elements to the list by appending them to the `UL` and then refresh the JQM listview:

```
$("#playerRoles").append(htmlList);
try {
    $("#playerRoles").listview('refresh'); 
} catch (e) { }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hdjLLdhw/7/